# Is there a simple way to save TMUX pane position and size

Tags: linux, terminal, raspbian, tmux

I have recently started using tmux with my raspberry pi and have set it up to open my session when I start SSH from my pc but when I restart my PI it closes the session and I lose my Pane setup. So is there a good way to save the position size of pane or even just save the session?

Comment: I wrote this: https://github.com/sk1418/retmux  you can try if you have python2 installed.

Comment: I have never tried using Python3 and 2 on the same machine would it be a problem having them both on there?

Comment: No   ......      . . . . .         .

Comment: Ok thanks i'll add that on there later

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [Tmux Resurrect](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect) plugin.

> Saves all the little details from your tmux environment so it can be completely restored after a system restart (or when you feel like it). No configuration is required.
>
> This plugin goes to great lengths to save and restore all the details from your tmux environment. Here's what's been taken care of:
>
> - all sessions, windows, panes and their order
> - current working directory for each pane
> - exact pane layouts within windows (even when zoomed)
> - active and alternative session
> - active and alternative window for each session
> - windows with focus
> - active pane for each window
> - "grouped sessions" (useful feature when using tmux with multiple monitors)
> - programs running within a pane! More details in the restoring programs doc.